# Javascript pagination for tabled content

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have content in a table that I need to paginate. I've tried finding a library for this, but I can't seem to find one that can deal with tables. Can anyone make a recommendation?

This is my table structure:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img>
        <p>
          <a></a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you may try this http://datatables.net/index..it only need to provide data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

try this (jQuery pagination plugin):
http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination